# Verilog assigning fractional value to integer

Tags: verilog

I am new to Verilog, but have some coding experience in VHDL. While reading someone else's code, I came across the following part:

```
genvar i;
generate
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i = i + 1) begin : gen_for
    integer p = (66.0*i)/8.0;
    assign data[p + 1] = ...
```

My doubt here is what will be the value of `p` rounded to? 
Will it be rounded to the nearest integer or to the largest integer `< (66.0*i)/8.0` (floor operation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever there's a decimal in an `integer` variable, it typically floors the value. So if the answer is like 8.25 for i=1, the answer would actually just be 8. Then at i=2, the answer will be 16.5 but with the integer variable will make it 16. And so forth.

You could also execute the code and see what it does :)